# PHP MVC: big application with multiple "modules"

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, model-view-controller

I'm writing a "application" in php using MVC (or some similar) and mod_rewrite, without FW.

the app has 3 modules: simple web page, admin area, user area

they all show different pages/sections

---

(array) modules: default = "", admin = "admin", users = "users"

- default_module = default
- default_controller = Index
- default_action = index

router check if URL[0] is a module or uses default module prefix and append to controller

I use "Generic Models" like: UsersModel, PagesModel, ConfigModel and any controller can call them.

---

**Solution 1: prefix for controllers or folder method: modulename/controllerfile**

```
Example URL's:

"Simple web page":

URL: domain.com/
Request: IndexController()->index();

URL: domain.com/some_page
Request: IndexController()->some_page();

URL: domain.com/some_page/some_param
Request: IndexController()->some_page(some_param);


"Admin Area": (edit contents, others...)

URL: domain.com/admin/
Request: AdminIndexController()->index();

URL: domain.com/admin/pages
Request: AdminPagesController()->index();

URL: domain.com/admin/pages/some_page
Request: AdminPagesController()->index(some_page);


"Users Area": (profle, others)

URL: domain.com/users/
Request: UsersIndexController()->index();

URL: domain.com/users/profile
Request: UsersProfileController()->index();

URL: domain.com/users/help
Request: UsersHelpController()->index();

URL: domain.com/users/help/help_1
Request: UsersHelpController()->help_1();
```

**Problem: too many controllers or controllers with same name (DRY)?**

---

**Solution 2: prefix for method**

```
Example URL's:

"Simple web page":

URL: domain.com/
Request: IndexController()->index();

URL: domain.com/some_page
Request: IndexController()->some_page();

URL: domain.com/some_page/some_param
Request: IndexController()->some_page(some_param);


"Admin Area": (edit contents, others...)

URL: domain.com/admin/
Request: IndexController()->Adminindex();

URL: domain.com/admin/pages
Request: PagesController()->Adminindex();

URL: domain.com/admin/pages/some_page
Request: PagesController()->Adminindex(some_page);


"Users Area": (profle, others)

URL: domain.com/users/
Request: IndexController()->Usersindex();

URL: domain.com/users/profile
Request: ProfileController()->Usersindex();

URL: domain.com/users/help
Request: HelpController()->Usersindex();

URL: domain.com/users/help/help_1
Request: HelpController()->Usershelp_1();
```

**Problem: SUPER fat controllers**

---

which one is the best way? or is there another way?